# query sqlite for specific column

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

i try to query for all data in specific colum but result in error "make sure that cursor initialized correctly before accessing thedata". is there any problem with this code thank you.

```
    public List<String> getAllItemName(){
    String[] column = new String[]{Pro_ID, Pro_Name, Pro_Price, Pro_Description, Pro_Date};
    Cursor c= ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " + Pro_Name + " From "+ TABLE_NAME , null);

    List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
     if (c.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
             lst.add(c.getString(1));
                              String name = c.getString(1);
                              Log.v(name,name + ("   name"));
         } while (c.moveToNext());
     }

     return lst;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cursor Indexes are 0 based. First column corresponds to :`c.getString(0)`.

You can get index of a column using `getColumnIndex(columnName)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead of c.getString(1):

```
c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Pro_Name))
```